# Is Iran in compliance with JCPOA?

Tags: iran, jcpoa

[In a public Facebook post, Barack Obama wrote](https://www.facebook.com/barackobama/posts/10155854913976749):

> Fourth, Iran is complying with the JCPOA. That was not simply the view of my Administration. The United States intelligence community has continued to find that Iran is meeting its responsibilities under the deal, and has reported as much to Congress. So have our closest allies, and the international agency responsible for verifying Iranian compliance – the International Atomic Energy Agency (IAEA).

Is this true, or has Iran violated the nuclear deal?

Comment: I found an [article from Politifact](http://www.politifact.com/georgia/statements/2017/jun/14/karen-handel/iran-complying-nuclear-deal-yes-small-hiccups/) indicating that Iran had a couple of minor violations, but quickly rectified them. As a result, a statement like, "Iran is in compliance," was reasonable. However, this was written a year ago. Is it still an accurate picture of the situation?

Comment: Quick searches online only show the Heavy Water limits being exceeded a couple times, and both times before the last time Trump re-certified the Iran deal.  John Bolton has claimed there are violations, but refuses to cite any besides the HW limit breaches, only saying "there were other breaches than that".

Comment: The headline claims from the Trump administration were that Iran was doing a bunch of other bad things not that the core treaty had be violated. They wanted the treaty to be broader in constraining Iran; they didn't claim it had been violated as such.

Comment: @matt_black Honestly, that's a big part of the reason I quoted Obama instead of someone from the Trump camp. It was easier for me to find a notable claim saying that Iran _was_ in compliance than it was to find a claim that it _wasn't_.

Comment: Our closest ally is Israel, so no.

Comment: @KDog I would say that most of the nations in Western Europe are closer allies than Israel.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to the IAEA: **Iran is compliant.**

The IAEA issued [this statement](https://www.iaea.org/newscenter/statements/statement-by-iaea-director-general-yukiya-amano-9-may-2018) by its Director General Yukiya Amano on 2018-05-09:

> The IAEA is closely following developments related to the Joint
>   Comprehensive Plan of Action (JCPOA). As requested by the United
>   Nations Security Council and authorised by the IAEA Board of Governors
>   in 2015, the IAEA is verifying and monitoring Iran’s implementation of
>   its nuclear-related commitments under the JCPOA. Iran is subject to
>   the world’s most robust nuclear verification regime under the JCPOA,
>   which is a significant verification gain. As of today, the IAEA can
>   confirm that the nuclear-related commitments are being implemented by
>   Iran.

Also: *If* the USA has proof of violations it should submit this proof to the IAEA and the UN security council (the JCPOA was [endorsed by the UN Security Council](http://United%20Nations%20Security%20Council%20Resolution%202231)).

Answer (score 9):

Obviously, Iran could be out of compliance and hiding it so well no one else knows. Here, however, is what the US Government has to say:

> [Secretary of State](https://nypost.com/2018/05/08/trump-says-hes-pulling-us-out-of-iran-nuclear-deal/) Mike Pompeo [and recent director of the
>   CIA – AL] had said in recent weeks that there was no evidence that
>   Iran breached the deal. “I’ve seen no evidence that they are not in
>   compliance,” Pompeo told the Senate recently.